# How can I view Live Photos in Ventura (Photos 8.0)?

Tags: photos, ventura

This is making me feel pretty dumb. Live photos used to work great, but since I upgraded to Ventura (13.0/22A380) and Photos 8 (511.0.180), I don't understand how they're supposed to work. Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: Trying to view a Live Photo]

There's the little "LIVE" button up in the corner. I used to click that to view the video (the "live" part of a live photo). But now when I move the mouse toward it, it disappears. Then when I move away, it's back. It's like a joke.

Clicking where the live button *was* does nothing. So… what am I missing here? How do Live Photos work in Photos 8?

Comment: I've just tried this on my device, and hovering over the icon plays the live photo (clicking doesn't seem to do anything?).

Does this occur to you on all devices?

Comment: @Ezekiel I've only upgraded to Ventura on one device, so that's all I got for reference. It does it consistently on that device though (iMac Pro 2017).

Comment: I misspoke, I meant "all your photos"

Comment: @Ezekiel Yes, this behavior happens consistently to all my photos in all my photo libraries.

Comment: My best guess is that it's a bug thats been resolved in macOS 13.1 (still in beta)